# React Beautiful Drag and Drop not work for me

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

Why this code not work form me. I can't understand. I try to learn react-beautiful-dnd. This is my code:

Column.jsx

```
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

const Column = () => {
  const itemList = [
    { id: "1", task: "Pierwszy element" },
    { id: "2", task: "Drugi element" },
    { id: "3", task: "Trzeci element" },
    { id: "4", task: "Czwarty element" },
    { id: "5", task: "Piąty element" },
    { id: "6", task: "Szósty element" },
  ];

  return (
    <DragDropContext>
      <div className="border-4 border-base-300 bg-base-300 mx-auto mt-2 w-[500px] rounded-md font-sans">
        <h1 className="text-center p-1 text-lg font-bold">
          Drag and drop list
        </h1>
        <Droppable droppableId="characters">
          {(provided) => (
            <ul
              className="bg-base-300 characters"
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
            >
              {itemList.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <Draggable key={item.id} draggableId={item.id} index={index}>
                    {(provided) => (
                      <li
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                        className="font-sans p-3 text-[15px] my-2 last:my-0 bg-base-200"
                      >
                        {item.task}
                      </li>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                );
              })}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </ul>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </div>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
};

export default Column;
```

If i try drag item, i have error. I can't find the solution.
[Result if i try drag item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzAZl.png)

Please help me, where i have error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell which version you are using. But I had the same issue after updating to react v18 where I needed to disable strict mode. But it could be fixed by now I don't know, maybe dive into the GitHub repo and search for that issue to find more information.

But as a quick fix, either remove

```
<React.StrictMode>
```

from your components.

Or if you are using nextJS, change that line inside your next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening due to React.Strict mode and might be an development issue
however you can render the Draggable with if logic block and render that component as a child of

e.g

```
const DragComp = () =>{
    const [enabled,setEnabled] = useState(false);
   
React.useEffect(()=>{
    const animation = requestAnimationFrame(() => setEnabled(true));

return () => {
       cancelAnimationFrame(animation);
       setEnabled(false);
    };
},[]);

    if(!enabled){
        return null;
    }
return (
<Draggable {...dragProps} >
{props.children}
</Draggable>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @m_wer answered, removing `StrictMode` is a temporary solution and is not a good idea in the long run since `StrictMode` lets you find common bugs in your components early during development. I would suggest the following solution. It works with `StrictMode` on.

```
// Credits to https://github.com/GiovanniACamacho and https://github.com/Meligy for the TypeScript version
// Original post: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/2399#issuecomment-1175638194

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Droppable, DroppableProps } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

export const StrictModeDroppable = ({ children, ...props }: DroppableProps) => {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const animation = requestAnimationFrame(() => setEnabled(true));
    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(animation);
      setEnabled(false);
    };
  }, []);
  if (!enabled) {
    return null;
  }
  return <Droppable {...props}>{children}</Droppable>;
};
```

[Source](https://medium.com/@wbern/getting-react-18s-strict-mode-to-work-with-react-beautiful-dnd-47bc909348e4)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34313701)

Comment: Will edit my answer to include the exact solution. Thank you for the correction